# How to Fill Out a Document in Google Docs

Tags: google-docs

In a Google Document, how would I type "over" a line created by underscores or achieve a similar looking result?

I would like to type my responses in the designated areas indicated by the underscores (similar to a typewriter) rather than printing the document and writing in the responses by hand.

In the example picture below, I attempted to type the text that was underlined, but as you can see, the underline and underscore are misaligned.

[image: screen shot]

Answer (score 3):

Change the font you use. Times New Roman still shows a difference, but not as marked:

[image: WA67205 first example]

Arial no difference (on top of Arial):

[image: WA67205 second example]